# Powershell: How to catch "No User exists for *"?

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell and the command `query user` to get the currently connected Users:

```
$Users = query user

if ($Users) {
    return $true }
else {
    return $false}
```

This will work fine, as log an User is currently connected:

[image]

But if no User is Connected, I receive the expected `False` + the unexpected Error: `No User exists for *`

[image]

How can I surpress the Error?

`$ErrorActionPreference= 'SilentlyContinue'` or `$Users = query user -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will not work, because query.exe doesn't accept powershell parameters.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stderr to void? (`2>$null`)?

Answer (score 5):

In simple terms, because query user is NOT a Powershell commandlet, you have to capture the output and process it yourself:

```
$Computer = 'localhost'

$Query = quser /server:$Computer 2>&1
If ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    $ErrorDetail = $Query.Exception.Message[1]
    Switch -Wildcard ($Query) {
        '*[1722]*' { 
            $Status = 'Remote RPC not enabled'
        }
        '*[5]*' {
            $Status = 'Access denied'
        }
        'No User exists for*' {
            $Status = 'No logged on users found'
        }
        default {
            $Status = 'Error'
            $ErrorDetail = $Query.Exception.Message
        }
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{ErrorStatus = $Status;ErrorMessage = $ErrorDetail}
}
Else { 
    $Query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! @Scepticalist pointed me into the right direction!

First I query the Users:

```
$Query = quser 2>&1
```

Secondly, I am looking for the String ID (this indicates, that there is a valid result)

```
if ($Query -match "ID") {
return $true }
else ( return $false }
```